# How to get the size (length) of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, string-length

For example, I get a string:

```
str = "please answer my question"
```

I want to write it to a file.

But I need to know the size of the string before writing the string to the file. What function can I use to calculate the size of the string?

Comment: "what function can i use to calculate the size of the string"?  What tutorial are you using to learn Python?  Please **update** the question with some information on where and how you're learning Python.

Comment: i learn python by myself,now  i  know the len(str) can return the size of string,the size  depends on the coding of the str.

Comment: What will be the size of the file after writing it? Let's assume the file was of zero sizes before writing.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

If you are talking about the length of the string, you can use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len):

```
>>> s = 'please answer my question'
>>> len(s)  # number of characters in s
25
```

If you need the size of the string in bytes, you need [`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(s)
58
```

Also, don't call your string variable `str`. It shadows the built-in [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` returns the number of bytes the Python object occupies in memory. That isn't going to be useful for writing to a file in any circumstances.

Comment: thanks,but sys.getsizeof(s) is just the size of the file?    or the size of  python object?

Comment: @cryanbhu I don't know why the OP wanted the size and that would affect the answer, but probably most useful would be `len(s.encode('utf8'))` or whatever other encoding is going to be used when writing to the file. Also, if they also want a terminating null then they'll need to add 1 for that.

Answer (score 45):

### Python 3:

[user225312's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967619/4518341) is correct:

**A.** To count number of characters in `str` object, you can use `len()` function:

```
>>> print(len('please anwser my question'))
25
```

**B.** To get memory size in bytes allocated to store `str` object, you can use `sys.getsizeof()` function

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> print(getsizeof('please anwser my question'))
50
```

### Python 2:

It gets complicated for Python 2.

**A.** The `len()` function in Python 2 returns count of bytes allocated to store *encoded characters* in a `str` object.

Sometimes it will be equal to character count:

```
>>> print(len('abc'))
3
```

But sometimes, it won't:

```
>>> print(len('йцы'))  # String contains Cyrillic symbols
6
```

That's because `str` can use [variable-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code) internally. So, to count characters in `str` you should know which encoding your `str` object is using. Then you can convert it to [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) object and get character count:

```
>>> print(len('йцы'.decode('utf8'))) #String contains Cyrillic symbols 
3
```

**B.** The `sys.getsizeof()` function does the same thing as in Python 3 - it returns count of bytes allocated to store *the whole string object*

```
>>> print(getsizeof('йцы'))
27
>>> print(getsizeof('йцы'.decode('utf8')))
32
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> len(s)
4
```

Answer (score 4):

You also may use str.len() to count length of element in the column

```
data['name of column'].str.len()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most *Pythonic* way is to use the `len()`. Keep in mind that the '\' character in escape sequences is not counted and can be dangerous if not used correctly.

```
>>> len('foo')
3
>>> len('\foo')
3
>>> len('\xoo')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to find the length of the string in the Python language? If you want to find the length of the word, you can use the *len* function.

```
string = input("Enter the string: ")

print("The string length is: ", len(string))
```

Output:

> Enter the string: viral
>
> The string length is: 5

Comment: 1 - why to add similar answer as the accepted one?
2 - your output is similar with your code, edit it or consider removing this redundant and incomplete answer...

Answer (score 0):

The responses provided are apt, but it is important to note that in Python, blank spaces are also considered characters.

However, if one wishes to create a function that requires counting total characters in someone’s name for instance, it may be necessary to remove blank spaces. This can easily be accomplished using the `.replace()` method.

For example:

```
name = "Steve Wozniak"
number = len(name.replace(" ", ""))
print(number)
```

The output here is **12** (excluding blank space) instead of **13** (including blank space).

Comment: There are [2,161,081 Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). This sounds like an answer to a different question, like *[How can I count characters in a string without the white spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969971/)*.