# How to check How many characters are in a String or Interger Input? Python 3.3.0

Tags: python-3.x

So I Have Some Work For School And A Task Asks To See How Many Characters Are In A String.

I Don't Even Know Where To Start.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the size of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967580/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I would start by reading the Python docs by the string functions section

Comment: @fredtantini I'll Look Into It

Comment: @Oscar Thanks, Will Do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str = "example"`

`print ("Length of the string: ", len(str))`

Comment: I Have Done This, And It Has Brought Up The Code And Says It Can't Convert Int to Str implicitly. I know I have to put string around it but there is already a len so is it possible to do print("Length: " + str(len(string)))